# Power calculations for multiple treatments

Tags: experiment-design, sample-size, statistical-power

I am starting a new project and need to determine the sample size needed to be able to determine statistically if there is a difference between treatment and control groups. I was going to use power calculations in order to determine the sample size needed. However the one wrinkle is that the team we are working with would like to test 3 different treatments. At this point I am unsure of the effect size between treatments and I am a little bit at a loss on how to determine sample size if I would like to make comparisons between treatments as well as control groups.